# Java - Modifying getSelectedValue() from JList

Tags: java

I have a JList which is full of cars, represented by their names.
Like : 
-GT
-206x
-personalCar
-...

The thing is : when i select a value, the **getSelectedValue()** method return the String displayed on the list. 
I want to have the ID of the car, and have the **getSelectedValue()** modified to return the ID. So I created a class extending JLabel and implementing ListCellRenderer which contains an ID. The JList set this class as his cellRenderer.

How can I override the **getSelectedValue()** method to return not the name of the car, but the ID inside the JLabel?

Thanks for your time!

edit : If you wanna see the code i'm trying to have :

```
    list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        String ID = ((JList) e.getSource()).getSelectedValue();
        //this method returns not the value of the JLabel clicked, but the ID inside 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSelectedValue()` does return the object that you added to the list. Your problem is that you probably added just the text and not an object holding the id. The value displayed by the `JList` is generated using the `toString()` method, so as long as your `Car` class has a both a suitable `toString()` and a `getId()` method, all you have to do is pass in the `Car` object instead of just its name.